# Setting Variable Assignments with property display

Tags: javascript

I'm still a novice when it comes to JavaScript and was trying to make my code more cleaner and was wondering why the top scenario works but the bottom doesn't? Am I missing something?

```
var partner = document.getElementById('partner');
var providedBy = document.getElementById('providedBy');

partner.style.display = "none";
providedBy.style.display = "none";
```

But this does not?

```
var partner = document.getElementById('partner');
var providedBy = document.getElementById('providedBy');
collection = partner + providedBy;

collection.style.display = "none";
```

In the console it gives me error saying Cannot set Property 'display' of undefined. Am I supposed to define it somewhere first? I console logged the new variable and it returned both div elements.

Comment: you are mising the closing `'` in `document.getElementById('providedBy);`

Comment: Sorry typo I have that included in my code and it still doesn't work

Comment: In JavaScript you have to declare all of your variables. Secondly, you can't point to two objects at once by using the + operator. JavaScript interprets this as trying to concatenate the two objects, which it can't do in this way. In order to affect two Objects at the same time you would need to create a function.

Comment: hey you cant add any element...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript you have to declare all of your variables. Secondly, you can't point to two objects at once by using the + operator. JavaScript interprets this as trying to concatenate the two objects, which it can't do in this way. It will return the string `[object Object][object Object]`

In order to affect two Objects at the same time you would need to create a function or use an existing method.

Comment: @torazaburo well, In the OPs case it wouldn't return anything. Can you elaborate what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

`collection` is of type string as the `+` operator automatically call for both their `toString()` function.

Now what you are trying is to access a property of `collection.style` which does not exist because you are operating on a string. That's the reason for the error message you are getting.

You could do something like:

```
var collection = [];
collection.push(document.getElementById('partner'));
collection.push(document.getElementById('providedBy'));
collection.forEach(function(element) {
    element.style.display = 'none';
}
```

which would be something I think you are trying to archive.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

just to complement the accepted answer, I think you should understand why you get this error.

For what i understand from your code, you are trying to set the css of both `variables` partner and `providedBy` to `display : none`.

Your first piece of code works because you do this separately, while in your second code you try to add with the (+) operator both nodes, which evaluates to the string "[object HTMLDivElement][object HTMLInputElement]".

Then you try to call `.style` on that string which evaluates to `undefined`, and then you try to call display on that undefined value, this is where you get the error.

You could leave your code just like that since there are not too many variables, but if you wanted to do something that worked on multiple variables you could

1. create an array
2. push your objects into the array
3. create a function that loops over the elements of the array and set their style.display = "none" to individually.

Comment: This is more clear but I already accepted the answer I'll give you and the other guy +1 for helping me understand it better thanks!

Comment: don't worry, the important thing is that you understand what's going on